# How do i get the redis store client from socket-io-redis?

Tags: node.js, socket.io, node-redis

**socket-io-redis** use redis inside to connect, I wonder how can i get the redis store client from the library so that i can use that client to store key value pairs in redis.

```
var redis   = require('socket.io-redis');
var socketio = require('socket.io');

io = socketio.listen(app);    
io.adapter(redis({ host: 'localhost', port: 6379 }));
```

I am using node cluster model, So i do not want to create a new redis client as i already have one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's shown [here](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-redis#client-error-handling):

```
var adapter   = redis({ host: 'localhost', port: 6379 });
var pubClient = adapter.pubClient;
io.adapter(adapter);
```

There's also an equivalent `adapter.subClient`, but you shouldn't use that (clients running in *"subscribe"* mode shouldn't be used for regular Redis commands).

I'm not sure if it's wise to use the `pubClient` to issue commands, either. Redis can handle multiple connections just fine, and it's easy to create a new client from the `pubClient` instance:

```
var pubClient = adapter.pubClient.duplicate();
```

Comment: I thought having multiple connections will not be a wise choice and it will slow down redis, but thanks to clear my doubt, I would rather create a new redis client.  
Is there any difference between creating a new client like this 
require('redis').createClient(host,port); than creating it from pubClient ?

Comment: @bikash the only difference is that when using `duplicate()`, you don't have to pass the connection options (server, credentials, etc) again. Aside from that, it's the same.